# Solving second order differential equation in python

Tags: python, ode, odeint

I want to solve second ODE's with the help of python.

The objective is:

d^2V/dx^2 = h*sin(e*x)

dV/dx = 0

Some info: L is the thickness of a plate, and it is equal to 5 mm. x is the position in the plate and goes from 0 to L. V is the electrical potential.

I dont understand how to put this in the code.

So far i have done this in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math

rho_0 =3.3*10**16 #C/m^3
epsilon = 2.1*10**10 #Nm^2/C^2

L = 5*10**-3


h = rho_0/epsilon
e = (4*math.pi)/L

def dV_dx(x,V):
   return [h*np.sin(e*x)]

t = np.linspace(0,1,100)

sol = odeint(model,y,t) #need to put in the 'model',and 'y' value above in the code
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your function should be`[x[1], -h*sin(e*x[1])]`

Comment: what about the initial values? how do one write them?